# Remove built-in like via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to delete Facebook OG Like.

First of all, I've created OG action:

```
POST /me/[app-namespace]:begin 
day = [day-page-url]
```

Then I've created like for it from another user:

```
POST /me/og.likes
object = [day-page-url]
```

Finally, let's try to delete like from the same user that created it (id was returned in the previous action):

```
DELETE 104127963073059
```

Debug says that this is definitely like ID.

But the result is:

```
(#10) Application does not have permission for this action
```

We use permissions:

```
email,user_birthday,user_location,publish_actions,publish_stream
```

You can check this via debugger tool:

```
App ID: 395096416536617 : ODM TEST
User ID:    100004287038925 : Foo
Issued: Unknown
Expires:    1346684400 (in about an hour)
Valid:  True
Origin: Unknown
Scopes: create_note email photo_upload publish_actions publish_stream share_item status_update user_birthday user_location video_upload
```

Check this once more with cURL:

```
Andrew-MacBook-Pro:onedayofmine macuser$ curl -X DELETE \
> -F 'access_token=AAAFnVo0zuqkBA...0gSDLRbj' \
> https://graph.facebook.com/104156136403575
{"error":{"message":"(#10) Application does not have permission for this action","type":"OAuthException","code":10}}
```

Maybe I need some additional permissions?

Comment: Just tried your steps with my test app and it deleted the action `app_namespace:begin` just fine.  Are you sure you are using the id of the `begin` action and not the id of the object `day`?  I am using perms `publish_actions,read_stream`

Comment: Check again that you are trying to delete action `begin` (of user1) and not `like` (of user2).

Comment: Im trying to delete like, not begin action. For example when user unlikes post.

Comment: I was able to delete the `like` action too.  Here's the like action created by my `user2`:  {"data":[{"id":"3639745067497","from":{"name":"John Smith","id":"10XXX648"},...,"application":{"name":"Article Liker","namespace":"article_liker","id":"364XX311647"},"data":{"object":{"id":"343299145761433","url":"http:\/\/example.com\/js_like_show_authtoken.php","type":"article_liker:review","title":"Article Two"}},"type":"og.likes", ...  And here I deleted it: curl -X DELETE -F 'access_token=AAAFLVZAuGuN...TZAWlqaIZAx' https://graph.facebook.com/3639745067497
true

Answer (score 0):

Moved to answer box for readability:

I was able to delete the `like` action too.

Here's the like action created by my `user2`:

```
{"data":[{"id":"3639745067497","from":{"name":"John Smith","id":"10XXX648"},...,"application" {"name":"Article Liker","namespace":"article_liker","id":"364XX311647"},"data":{"object":{"id":"343299145761433","url":"http:\/\/example.com\/js_like_show_authtoken.php","type":"article_liker:review","title":"Article Two"}},"type":"og.likes", ...
```

And here I deleted it:

```
curl -X DELETE -F 'access_token=AAAFLVZAuGuN...TZAWlqaIZAx' https://graph.facebook.com/3639745067497
true
```

Where, `true` = success

Access token perms:

```
Scopes: publish_actions read_stream
```

Comment: It seems to be bug, i've found few of them in FB bugtracker... Test users just dont work, sometimes.